# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#1-of ? extends EntityObject> to List<T>

Tags: java, generics

In the following snippet, I get a type mismatch error.

```
public abstract class EntityObject {
}

public class Business {
    public <T extends EntityObject> List<T> get(T entity) {

    MyService myService = new MyService();

    // Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<capture#1-of ? extends EntityObject> to List<T>
    return myService.get(entity.getClass()); // how to program here?
    }
}

public class MyService {
    public <T extends EntityObject> List<T> get(Class<T> entityClass) {

    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //....
    return list;
    }
}
```

It cannot convert from `List<capture#1-of ? extends EntityObject>` to `List<T>`. 
I'm not familiar with the complex generic type. How to call the `get` method of  `MyService` class in the `get` method of `Business` class.
How to modify the code I mentioned in the snippet?

I could use `(List<T>)myService.get(entity.getClass());` to force the conversion. But I'm not sure it's a good idea.

Comment: You're trying to put a List of some subclass of `EntityObject` in a List of some subclass of `EntityObject`. Those subclasses don't have to be the same which means that putting one in the other might not be successful. Java tells you this with the type mismatch error. Returning a `List<EntityObject>` from `Business#get` should remove the error, but I don't know if you want that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java). I could have written a new answer here, but I think the answers to that question are better than what I would make of it.

Comment: `MyService` is class that another project offers. If possible, I wouldn't change it. I want to modify where I call it.

Comment: That's what I said, change the return type of your `Business#get` to `List<EntityObject>`.

Comment: `List<EntityObject>` is also wrong, `List<? extends EntityObject>` instead.
But I don't know if it is the best practice.